# Nginx is gziping but is doing same thing for each request on same never changed JS file

Tags: nginx, caching, gzip

I have nginx serving some static files including one JavaScript file.

```
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_disable msie6;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_buffers 8 4k;
  gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
  gzip_vary on;
```

gzip works but not how I would like it to work.

JavaScript file is never changed. There is no reason to gzip it on each request. I'd like to gzip it once and keep it in RAM and serve it ASAP.

Is it possible with nginx? Do I need Varnish or something similar to get it done?

Comment: how are you testing and what are you expecting, how would you like it to work?

Comment: @nbari 1. I've toggled gzip compression level from 1 to 9 to see how long it takes to have max compression. 2. I've checked in incognito sessions how long it takes for 1st call and for n-th call (new session for each to bypass browser caching)